# Flex 4: Having slider and textbox combo

Tags: forms, flex4, textinput

On a flex project, I have a slider and text box on a form whereby I seek user input using either the slider(for ease) or the textinput(for precise numbers). Based on user input on either of these, I update the other via a listener attached, that calls the relevant functions

```
slider.addEventListener("change",sliderUpdate);
textIn.addEventListener("change",valueUpdate);
```

I am having problems with the textinput in that, it doesn't allow me to key in a decimal number- this is probably happening as I have a listener that is incrementing the slider for every keystroke in textinput and hence unable to accept a ".". e.g. .05, .1, .00003

How do I get around this- can i hold the textinput listener to holdoff till I can press an enter to indicate I am done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">    
        <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

            protected function sliderUpdate(event:Event):void
            {
                textIn.text=slider.value.toString();
            }

            protected function valueUpdate(event:TextOperationEvent):void
            {
                slider.value=Number(textIn.text);
            }
        ]]>
        </fx:Script>
        <s:HSlider id="slider" x="10" y="106" width="308" change="sliderUpdate(event)" maximum="100.0" minimum="0.0" stepSize="0.01"/>
        <s:TextInput id="textIn" x="10" y="76" width="87" change="valueUpdate(event)" text="0"/>
    </s:Application>
```

The slider's step value is 0.01; If you input a value in the text field the slider should automatically update.

**EDIT:**

Then on the TextInput you should listen for the keyDown event (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN) and the function should check if the key pressed is ENTER and then update the slider:

```
<s:TextInput id="textIn" x="10" y="76" width="87" keyDown="textIn_keyDownHandler(event)" text="0"/>
```

The function:

```
    protected function textIn_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
        {
            slider.value=Number(textIn.text);
        }
    }
```

If you prefer to use addEventListener the this should do it:

```
textIn.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, textIn_keyDownHandler);
```

Comment: I clarified the question around what I meant by decimal points. For business reasons, I need the slider to have a different snap value which goes at higher increments. My challenge is not for 6.01, 2.005 etc work for me- challenge with .009, ,045 etc- it doesnt allow the '.' as the slider tries to update for every keystroke

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but why using two thumbs is not working even i update the values array?